# Clarification on definition of a norm in a real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis

I was given a problem in my real analysis class and I'm having some trouble understanding a part of the question. The question reads as follows:

> Let $(X, \lVert \cdot\rVert)$ be a normed vector space.
>
> Prove that $X^* = \{f: X \to \mathbb{R}, f $ linear and continuous $\}$ with the "operator norm" $$ \lVert f \lVert = \sup_{\lVert x \lVert = 1} \lVert f(x) \lVert$$ is a Banach space.

My plan on how to approach the question was to construct a cauchy sequence in $(X^*, \lVert \cdot\lVert$) and show it converges in $(X^*, \lVert \cdot\lVert)$. But I'm confused as to how the "operator norm" works (I wrote it down as it appeared on the page). There are a few norms in the definition for the operator norm and I'm confused as to what each one is. My interpretation was that $\lVert f \lVert$ and $\lVert f(x) \lVert$ are the "operator norm" and $\lVert x \lVert$ was the norm on $(X, \lVert\cdot  \lVert)$. Is that the correct way to read it?

Also, what is the significance of having $\lVert x \lVert = 1$ for the operator norm? Is there a reason that $\lVert x \lVert = 1$? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, often this issue is made more clear with notation I will show presently. The norm on the $x$ in your equation is the norm $X$ came with, and the norm on $f$ is the one on $\mathbb{R}$, where $f$ sends things, i.e. the absolute value. This is sometimes denoted
$$
||f||=\sup_{||x||_X} ||f||_\mathbb{R}
$$

As for your idea, sounds great. It may be helpful to note that the supremum norm is often called "the norm of uniform convergence."

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, knowing that the norm on $f$ is the absolute value makes much easier to understand.